# Does 表示する have the meaning of "view"?

Tags: meaning, syntax

I saw a sentence on X(twitter):

> このアカウントの所有者はポストを表示できるアカウントを制限しているため、このポストを表示できません。

and was confused about the subject of "このポストを表示できません".
If 表示する has the meaning of "view", I could say:

> 君**は**このポストを表示できません。
> You cann't view this post.

and the subject would be the viewer who see this message.

But if 表示する means "show", I think the message would be

> X(twitter)**は**君**に**このポストを表示できません。
> X(twitter) cann't show this post to you.

and the subject would be the X(twitter).

Does my consideration make sense? If so, which one is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/70419/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

表示する means "to show, indicate, display", so your second interpretation is correct.